# Connecting Azure AD B2C tenant policies to a registered app

Tags: openid, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-b2c, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to find out why a .NET Core 2.0 Web App with OpenID Connect authentication using ADAL that connects to Azure AD B2C doesn't communicate with my Azure AD B2C tenant configuration, and most importantly the sign in policies. My app is very similar to [this](https://github.com/juunas11/aspnetcore2aadauth) one, except that I use Azure AD Graph.

My "authority" for `AuthenticationContext` is 
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizationname.onmicrosoft.com`

Due to this, user is forced to login with Microsoft account or a mail with tenant domain, where I'd like the user to login with his personal tenant account. Shouldn't the policies be applied automatically? I feel like I might be missing something important here.

The app sits in registered apps in Azure and has all the permissions needed.

I basically need to connect the policies from that tenant to my app's authentication system so it will accept local tenant accounts and not just those from Microsoft.

Or to put it in even simpler words: How to I add the part in the red circle to the url?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample you referenced is for regular Azure AD.

Check out [this sample for Azure AD B2C with .Net Core 2.0](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/tree/core2.0), in particular [OpenIdConnectOptionsSetup.cs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/blob/core2.0/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/OpenIdConnectOptionsSetup.cs) and [AzureAdB2COptions.cs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/blob/core2.0/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/AzureAdB2COptions.cs).

Key things to keep in mind:

- The authority has the following format: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/<yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com>/<default_policy>/v2.0` though the sample I referenced builds this automatically for you. By using this authority, the OWIN middleware and MSAL will both automatically pickup the `?policy=b2c_1_x` parameter from the metadata endpoint.

  ```cs
  public AzureAdB2COptions()
  {
      AzureAdB2CInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp";
  }
  //...other init code
  public string Authority => $"{AzureAdB2CInstance}/{Tenant}/{DefaultPolicy}/v2.0";
  ```
- You should use MSAL for your token redemption, not ADAL.

  ```cs
  public async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context)
  {
      var code = context.ProtocolMessage.Code;

      string signedInUserID = context.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
      TokenCache userTokenCache = new MSALSessionCache(signedInUserID, context.HttpContext).GetMsalCacheInstance();
      ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(AzureAdB2COptions.ClientId, AzureAdB2COptions.Authority, AzureAdB2COptions.RedirectUri, new ClientCredential(AzureAdB2COptions.ClientSecret), userTokenCache, null);
      try
      {
          AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, AzureAdB2COptions.ApiScopes.Split(' '));
          context.HandleCodeRedemption(result.AccessToken, result.IdToken);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          //Handle
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Hm, wouldn't switching to MSAL make using Azure Graph impossible though? The option of adding a large number of local accounts at once is at the core of my application.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you can't connect to Azure Graph if using MSAL, only to Microsoft Graph. And you can't use Microsoft Graph to add local account to your B2C tenant.

Comment: Not quite, Azure AD B2C tokens can't be used against either Graph (Microsoft or Azure AD) - see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44474803/manage-user-from-azure-ad-b2c-using-ad-graph-api-secure-access/44597650#44597650) for more info. You'll need to separately setup the client credentials flow to obtain an application token (versus a user token) for your Graph API operations.

Comment: Sorry, you're second comment came in after I posted my first comment. The best approach would be to separate out the web app that your user authenticates to versus the web API that calls the Graph to create users. Your web app is secured via Owin middleware by B2C and uses MSAL to obtain a token for your B2C web api.
Your web API is secured via Owin middleware by B2C and uses ADAL to obtain a token for the Azure AD graph.

Comment: So you have 3 app registrations - 1 B2C app registration for your web app, 1 B2C app registration for your web api, 1 Azure AD app registartion for your web api to call the Graph.

Comment: Sounds pretty complex, and to be honest I'm still just a beginner. Is there maybe some reference to projects that work similarily to that? I tried finding some to no avail.

Comment: The issue would mostly lie in connecting them.